# Create SQS dynamic with lambda function set

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Im new to AWS SQS and Im trying to create dynamic a SQS with triggers a lambda function. I could not find in AWS documentation`createQueue` something that connects this method with my lambda. I need to create a SQS Queue (With parameters - their apiKey for example) for each user in my website, because they will be able to create emails campaigns and I want to use SQS to manage then. So my users will be able to stop their campaigns because they will be connect to their SQS and the SQS with trigger lambda function to send the emails. Is it possible to do ? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would create the SQS queue, and the Lambda function. Then you would call the Lambda `createEventSourceMapping` API to register the queue as an event source for the Lambda function. For example in Python (you didn't say what language you were using):

```
lambda_client.create_event_source_mapping(
    EventSourceArn='ARN:OF:YOUR:SQS:QUEUE',
    FunctionName='YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME')
```

or in Java:

```
lambdaClient.createEventSourceMapping(
    new CreateEventSourceMappingRequest()
        .withEventSourceArn("ARN:OF:YOUR:SQS:QUEUE")
        .withFunctionName("YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME")
```

Comment: Im using nodejs. So I would have one lambda function and one SQS queue for each client right ? Can I dynamic copie my template lambda to this new lambda?

Comment: You can have multiple SQS queues sending messages to a single Lambda function. I don't understand the second question you are asking. What is a "template lambda"?

Comment: I need multiple SQS queues to send messages to a single Lambda function. If I create one lambda function and one SQS queue for each user, I will have multiple lambda functions for multiple user and that is not what I need. How can I have multiple SQS queues to send mesages to a single Lambda?

Comment: Just assign multiple SQS queues to a single Lambda function. There is nothing stopping you from doing that. Are you having an actual issue accomplishing that?

Comment: Yes that is my questions. How can I do that dynamic ? I will have a lot of users, I need to create it when my user create a new campaigns.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? What is my answer missing that you still need? You would simply use the same Lambda function name for every event source you create.

Comment: Lol, so I can register as many event source queue to the same lambda function?